# How to use make utility to check the errors in one of the C files?

Tags: c, linux, makefile

I am trying to change the code in one of C files in a project. Can I use make utility for the makefile of the project to compile and find out errors in that specific file( rest are fine) and re compile it till there are no errors P.S. I have not used make so far

Answer (score 1):

`Make` will only recompile files that have changed.  You can also use `make <filename>` to compile just that one file without even checking the rest, but that doesn't always work in projects with complex hierarchies of makefiles.

Comment: Since the OP doesn't know much about Make, I'd stick with "building" the entire project and letting Make manage what needs to be recompiled.

Comment: Me too, that's why I mentioned it doesn't always work.  It's worth a quick try, but I wouldn't waste any time debugging it.

Answer (score 0):

`make` compares the timestamp of every file with those of its compiled object file each time it is run. So if you have rules in a makefile compiling multiple files and run `make`, it will compile only those files that have been changed since the last time it was run.